# Get object id immediately after saving context

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm hoping someone can help me.  I am not using Parse and all the results Google pulls up are answers related to Parse.  I have some code where I save an entity to core data.  I want to immediately grab the object ID associated with the item directly after saving it.  Is there any way to do that?  See the code snippet below to see what I am talking about:

```
var appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Aquarium", inManagedObjectContext: context)
//Instance of our custom class, reference to entity
var newAquarium = UserAquariums(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
newAquarium.aquariumName = "Name of aquarium"

context.save(nil)
println("Context saved.")

//Here is where I have to figure out how to get the object ID of the aquarium directly after I saved it to the context. 
var aquariumObjectID: String
aquariumObjectID = ??????????
```

Comment: My memory may be off on this but I think it would be newAquarium.objectId

Comment: Thanks!  I think you're right.  It seems to work that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newAquarium.objectId
```

and yes, make sure it is saved to the database first.

I noticed you are using save which is performed synchronously. Do not use that from the main thread.

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't know there are alternatives to context.save, so this sends me down a whole new path of things to learn! :-)